# Connect 3D points in matplotlib scatter

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code, that generates a 3D scatter plot:

```
df_subset = pd.DataFrame(a_dict)

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
cmap = ListedColormap(sns.color_palette("husl", 256).as_hex())

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,15))
ax = Axes3D(fig)
fig.add_axes(ax)
sc = ax.scatter(tsne[:,0], tsne[:,1], tsne[:,2], s=40, c=tsne[:,0], marker='o', cmap=cmap, alpha=1)
ax.set_xlabel('First Dimention')
ax.set_ylabel('Second Dimention')
ax.set_zlabel('Third Dimention')
```

What I'm trying to do is connect those 2 points using a directional arrow.

[What I've got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vF4TA.png)

What I want:
[What i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Npu7m.jpg)

Tried `ax.annotation` but it doesn't work. Any suggestions? Preferencially, a for loop to annotate N points, considering the `(x1, y1, z1) and (x2, y2, z2)` coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a possible solution, `p1` and `p2` are just some points for testing purpose:

```
p1 = np.arange(4)
p2 = np.arange(4) * 2

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')

sc1 = ax.scatter(p1[0], p1[1], p1[2],c=p1[3], marker='o', cmap='jet')
sc2 = ax.scatter(p2[0], p2[1], p2[2],c=p2[3], marker='o', cmap='jet')

ax.set_xlabel('First Dimension')
ax.set_ylabel('Second Dimension')
ax.set_zlabel('Third Dimension')

ax.quiver3D(p1[0], p1[1], p1[2], (p2[0]-p1[0]), (p2[1]-p1[1]), (p2[2]-p1[2]), length=1, arrow_length_ratio=0.1)
```

Output:

[image]

basically `ax.quiver3D` has following parameter in the parenthesis:

```
(x, y, z, dx, dy, dz)
```

`x, y, z` is the initial position and `dx, dy, dz` is the vector direction.

As for the loop, I think you will manage to adapt the code yourself, will you?